# Java - Round number up so number of digits increments

Tags: java, performance, rounding

What is the most efficient way (in Java) to round a number n up to the nearest power of ten which contains one more digit than the original number?

e.g.
3 -> 10

432 -> 1,000

241,345 -> 1,000,000

Is there a way to get it in a single O(1) line?

A simple way I can see is to use a for loop and increment the power of ten until n / (10 ^ i) < 1, but then that isn't O(1) and is O(log n) instead. (well I'm taking a guess it's log n as it involves a power!)

Comment: I have an answer but I want to make sure, the input is going to be int? Or should we expect long too?

Comment: For your purposes, is arithmetic O(1)?

Comment: Isn't there a name for this like Feynmann estimates or something? I recall seeing it on NumberPhile

Comment: Another "stupid" way to do it would be to convert the number to string, take the length of the string, and append that many zeros to "1".  (Of course, the string conversion is log(N), but it seems that all of the other answers involve log(N) as well. ;))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a string, you can use [`Math.log10`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10-double-) to find the right index into an array:

```
// Do more of these in reality, of course...
private static final String[] MESSAGES = { "1", "10", "100", "1,000", "10,000" };

public static final String roundUpToPowerOf10(int x) {
    return MESSAGES[(int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(x))];
}
```

If you want it to return the integer with the right value, you can use use `Math.pow`:

```
public static final int roundUpToPowerOf10(int x) {
    return (int) Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(x)));
}
```

Comment: Without an array you could probably do `Math.pow( 10, (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(x)) ) `so avoid the hardcoding and be more generalised.

Comment: Yeah, probably no need to use the array.

Comment: Haha after leaving the problem for a couple of minutes I finally remember the log function does indeed exist(!!!), come back to admit my momentary ignorance and find Jon Skeet has beaten me to it!

Although I do like the idea of the array for performance.

Comment: @ArtB: True - I interpreted the question to be wanting to get to a string representation, but will add an "int to int" method too.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
double input = ...
double output = Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(input)));
```

You can cast your output to an integer then. The operations amount is constant so O(1) is guaranteed for a single input.

Comment: A way to remember; the floor is below you, and the ceiling is above. ;)