# Round number up to nearest quarter

Tags: java, rounding

I want to round `n` up to the nearest quarter, so

- 3.00 < n < 3.25 : rounds to 3.25
- 3.25 < n < 3.50 : rounds to 3.50
- 3.50 < n < 3.75 : rounds to 3.75
- 3.75 < n < 4.00 : rounds to 4.00

I have managed to round to next integer like this.

```
 double roundOff = Math.ceil(val)
```

I need the to know how to handle values below the x.75 threshold.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Round number up so number of digits increments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266195/java-round-number-up-so-number-of-digits-increments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can round the number times 4 then divide by 4:

```
double rounded = Math.ceil(val * 4) / 4;
```

You then need an extra condition to make sure that `rounded` is not greater than 4.